# Google App Engine - Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 404

Tags: google-app-engine, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api, ngrok

I'm using Google App Engine to develop a plugin for Atlassian JIRA.  They have recently changed around how to use development instances of Cloud JIRA.  It now uses an external, Atlassian hosted, version of JIRA Cloud (instead of a local copy).

To develop locally you need to run ngrok ([atlassian instructions](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/developing/developing-locally.html)) to communicate between your local server (for me Google App Engine running in Eclipse) and the external JIRA instance.

My problem is that this gives a 500 error reporting a 404 when it does the AJAX call to the Google App Engine end point.  The Servlet calls work fine.  The Javascript error is:

jquery.min.js:4 GET https://7d45c4d7.au.ngrok.io/_ah/api/myplugin/v1/addEdit?projectId=10001&id=-1 500 (Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 404)

The returned error if I try to put the URL into my browser is:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /_ah/api/myplugin/v1/addEdit. Reason:

    Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 404
Caused by:

java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 404
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.getApiConfigSources(ApiServlet.java:107)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.initConfigsIfNecessary(ApiServlet.java:72)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:117)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I have searched around and the only thing I can find is to add --address=0.0.0.0 to the program arguments (next to --port=8888) but this still doesn't work (actually makes no difference).

I found another article that said they got this type of error when not using @Named on the on the parameters being passed in but I have these for the called code.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951482/appengine-endpoint-failed-to-retrieve-api-configs-with-status-500

Comment: @Jehy I had already looked at that page but have tried again.  I have played around with the Api root, version, audiences, clientIds. Libraries are at latest. Last two don't apply.  Still not working.  Thanks

Comment: Ending up adding -host-header="localhost:8888" to ngrok and it now works.  The problem seems to be with Google App Engine endpoints rather than with ajax calls (servlets work fine)